# Angular 6 rxjs filter removing all entries from Observable

Tags: angular, filter, rxjs

I am loading a set of external page data via a JSON file. When left alone, my Observable is returning 4 items as expected:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Page }   from './page';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

pagesUrl  = 'http://localhost:4200/assets/pages.json';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getPage(slug): Observable<Page> {
  var pages = this.http.get<Page>(this.pagesUrl);
  return pages;
}
```

`pages` gives my component all of the data for the 4 pages.

However, when I try to filter `pages` to an item with a specific url, I end up with nothing:

```
getPage(slug): Observable<Page> {
  var url   = this.site + slug + "/";
  var pages = this.http.get<Page>(this.pagesUrl);

  const data = pages.pipe(
    filter(page => page.link == url)
  );
  const subscribe = pages.subscribe(p => console.log(p));

  return data;
}
```

`data` is returning nothing / null

I have checked 100x, my `url` var does indeed match the `link` string for one of the items in the JSON file.

and from my ./page.ts file:

```
export interface Page {
  id: number,
  link: string
}
```

Edit:

This code just produced the result I was looking for. However, I do not understand why removing `<Page>` from the Observable made the different. If someone can explain this to me, it would be much appreciated!

```
getPage(slug): Observable<any> {
  var url   = this.site + slug + "/";
  var pages = this.http.get<any>(this.pagesUrl);

  const data = pages.pipe(
    map(pages => pages.filter((page) => page.link == url))
  );

  const subscribe = pages.subscribe(p => console.log(p));

  return data;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since observable behave as async control, you can't return the data before observable subscribe. The best way you can do is instead of returning the data you can assign the pages into a variable and bind it to a template

```
data: Page[] = []

getPage(slug): void {
    var url = this.site + slug + "/";
    var pages = this.http.get < Page > (this.pagesUrl);
    pages.pipe(
        filter(page => page.link == url)
    );
    pages.subscribe(p => {
        this.data = p;
        console.log(this.data)
    });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `filter` function on `Observable` is for filtering the event stream, i.e. to filter how many times the `.subscribe` function is executed.

It sounds like you want to filter the value that is emitted. For that, you will need to use something like `.map` along with the [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function

```
const data = pages.pipe(
    map(pages => pages.filter((page) => page.link == url))
);
```

Comment: You are correct, I am trying to filter the value that is emitted. When I tried your code, I get `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Page'.`

Comment: The subscribe function is *always* called. You're talking about the next handler you pass into it.

Comment: Your HTTP call is typed to return a single page (`this.http.get<Page>`). Does it not return an array?

Comment: @IngoBürk What I mean is that, if the stream normally emits 4 separate events, (i.e. not one event with an array), then `filter` can be used to ensure it only emits values that pass its filter

Comment: Yes, it does return a set of 4 items in the JSON file. When I try using `<Page[]>`, get the following errors:

    Type 'Page[]' is not assignable to type 'Page'.
    Property 'id' is missing in type 'Page[]'.

Comment: @Philip The reason you need to remove <Page> is because a single page does not have a .filter function, so it wouldnt compile